# Консольная конвертация SVG в PPM,PNG

Tags: linux, svg, png

Имеется 1 **SVG** изображение, требуется это изображение сконвертировать в **PPM** формат (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_anymap) используя только консольные команды.

Разрешается конвертировать в **PNG** (или любой другой), а только потом в **PPM**.

Желательно иметь меньше зависимостей софта для этих манипуляций.

!!!Не предлагать такую вещь как **rsvg-convert** (шрифты не правильные, конкретно! шрифты калибри (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri) на рисунке превращяются в sans serif https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) или предложить исправление *rsvg-convert -w 1024 -h 768 рисунок.svg -o test.png*

Comment: Векторное в растровое? При конвертировании вам необходимо три параметра (как минимум): ширина, высота и разрешение. Скорее всего в ваших попытках вы не изменяли разрешение по умолчанию, которое обычно 72 dpi.

Comment: Ширина, высота присутствует. rsvg-convert делает то что надо, но, дело в том что при конвертации там шрифты не те (если у меня стоит шрифт калибри то он сделает из него sans serif).

Comment: Ну так поставьте шрифт Calibri в систему.

Comment: все уже придумано до нас... https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820965

Answer (score 0):

Можно при помощи imagemagick

```
convert test.svg test.ppm
```

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php